# Ubuntu 12.04 x32 - Windows 7 Pro x64 dual boot - clock is wrong (UTC)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, time, utc, boot

I have a problem with time when booting windows after linux. The reason is that Ubuntu saves hw clock as UTC but Windows 7 expects it to be saved as localtime. So Windows shows time that is one hour before correct local time.

- UTC time: 3:35PM
- Local time (UTC+1): 4:35PM
- Ubuntu time: 4:35PM
- Windows time: 3:35PM (it shows time that equals to UTC because it
  expects hw clock to be localtime)

I followed this advice:

> To make MS Windows calculate the time from the hardware clock as UTC.
>   Via regedit: Run regedit and navigate to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
>   Right-click in the right-side panel and select New > DWORD Value.
>   Create the key named RealTimeIsUniversal and give it a value of 1.

After restarting, windows shows time that is 1 hour ahead. My timezone is UTC+1 but time is set to UTC+2. If I set timezone to UTC, time is correct.

- UTC time: 3:35PM
- Local time (UTC+1): 4:35PM
- Ubuntu time: 4:35PM
- Windows time: 5:35PM (it shows time that equals to UTC+2 but timezone is
  set to UTC+1)

Setting ubuntu to save hw clock as localtime solves the problem with time but I want to have hw clock set to UTC.

Any suggestions?

Thx in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but did you verify in Windows there is no daylight savings setting?  That would account for an hour.  Sorry, my only idea!

Comment: Yes, I did but that is not the problem... Finally, I found a solution. It is very easy. After I had changed settings in regedit and restarted the pc, Windows wrote localtime to hw clock. After booting to windows, it started to use UTC so time was wrong. I just needed to boot linux that wrote UTC time to hw clock and then boot to windows and time is correct.

Comment: This applies to my Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 64bit as well. I'd suggest that you write your solution into an answer and then accept it.